# Bulk insert data if not exists & update data if exists in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to insert data to database if the record is not exists, and update the data in database if the record is exists.

I have 3 variable that stored the request from form:

```
$employee = $request->employee_id;
example value: "91fc7a4e-6201-4bc2-b2db-196f61d2d0cb"

$locations = $request->location_id;
example value: array:2 [▼
  0 => "ec0987b3-5bd9-11ec-ab79-98fa9b511cca"
  1 => "8300fca0-b63a-4bdb-ae08-8b08a9f58164"
  2 =>  etc
]

$can_checkin_by_location = $request->qr;
example value: array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "1"
  2 => etc
]
```

The value for `$locations` and `$can_checkin_by_location` is an array.

I have tried like code bellow, but I got error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'location_id ' in 'field list'`

```
foreach($locations as $key => $local)
  {
    $input['employee_id'] = $employee;
    $input['location_id '] = $local[$key];
    $input['can_checkin_by_location'] = $can_checkin_by_location[$key];

    EmployeeCustomLocation::upsert($input, 'employee_id');
  }
```

I just discovered `upsert` method today, so my understanding about `upsert` is very limited. Usually I'm using updateOrCreate for this kind of case, but I don't know what I have to do if I want to doing bulk insert or update using it

Comment: upsert method's first argument consists of the values to insert or update, while the second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table. And you wrote just "employee_id" in second argument of method.

Comment: same place you can use updateOrCreate for this. then  why using upsert ? any reason ?
BULK data we can do updateOrCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You have space after text `location_id` `['location_id ']`.

here is updated line:

```
$input['location_id'] = $local[$key];
```

**If this does not solve error**
`upsert` have three arguments for example

```
Flight::upsert([
['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], 
['departure', 'destination'],
['price']);
```

1- First argument consists of the values to insert or update.
2- Second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records
within the associated table.
3- third and final argument is an array of the columns that should be
updated if a matching record already exists in the database.

upsert worked like this:

Where in entire table:
`departure = Oakland` and  `destination = San Diego` then update `price =  99`.
Similarly where:
`departure = Chicago` and `'destination = New York` then update `price =  150`.